# Cannot create file with Chinese content in it

Tags: php, file, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to create a file as html to store Chinese characters for my internationalised site but they all appear as question marks.

If I store content of the page in database and pull it when the particular page is loaded, it will probably work fine but this means a connection to the database every time someone wants to see Chinese language.

Is there any way of doing it on flat files? I wanted to create a file and read it's content and display on the site.

Site runs on PHP+Mysql

Thanks

Comment: What encoding are you using in the html file? Have you set `Content-Type` in `head`?

Comment: Unicode is the way... To get flat files showing chinese characters, set correct charset in your page **and** encode your file in Unicode.

Comment: Both of these didn't work. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: the second should work, but what about the file itself ? can you confirm it is really Unicode ? (open it in your favorite IDE, Notepad++, eg.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Add "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8" to your site's .htaccess file.
2. Add header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); to the top of your PHP file.
3. Use utf8_encode() php function on the data that needs to be displayed in chinese.